# Automatically rerun something with sudo if root needed

Tags: command-line, sudo

I'm running Arch Linux in a virtual machine and it's getting REALLY annoying that since some thing require that I cannot be root, I need to sudo most of my commands. It would be nice if I could do something to detect a command needing root, and automatically run/re-run it with `sudo` giving it root powers. Can someone help me out with this? Thanks. Also, I know this isn't secure, but it's just a VM to experiment in. Also, I have NOT found any automatic solutions. I'm looking for an automatic solution, the question this is supposedly duplicate to does not have an answer that is automatic.

Comment: Oh, of course the way I say it makes different results. well then. I'll check that out

Comment: So the answer OP accepted doesn't actually answer the question ("How to do X?" "Here's how to do Y") and the supposed dupe's answers are even less helpful. The only remotely decent answers is https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/235470/217968 but even that doesn't really accomplish what the OP is asking (**automatically** rerun with sudo if needed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need to perform maintainence, upgrades, configuration and other tasks that require root, run `sudo -i` to get a root login shell (i.e. with all env vars, aliases, functions etc as if root had actually logged in).

Run whatever commands you need, create/edit/delete/move files, all as root - without needing to preface each command with `sudo`.  Type `exit` or `Ctrl-D` to exit the root shell and return to your user shell when you have finished.

Comment: Yes, but I mentioned how I need to run both root AND regular commands, so it would be easier for it to be seamless.

Comment: You can have a root terminal and a non-root terminal at the same time.

Comment: Maybe, it depends

Comment: BTW, what you want does not exist because anyone capable of writing such a thing would immediately realise that it was a disaster waiting to happen.  e.g. run 'rm -rf /' as a normal user...it recognises that root perms are required so auto re-runs the command with sudo. but you ran a sudo command only a few minutes ago so you aren't even prompted for a password before your disk is wiped.

Comment: Yeah, I might just need to get into coding myself and do some weird stuff to detect if a command needs root.

Answer (score 2):

I always use

```
sudo !!
```

Run the last command as root

```
su -c "!!"
```

Run the last command as root
Same as `sudo !!`. If you do not have permission to be sudo or sudo does not installed on your system, you can use this.

Comment: Yeah, I do that, but I want an AUTOMATIC solution. I don't want to have to run another command.

Comment: There is no automatic solution, as this would require each command to return a specific return code which would indicate it's missing execution privileges. You could give [thefuck](https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck) a try and in case you're a zsh user, there's even a nice [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) [plugin for thefuck](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/thefuck/thefuck.plugin.zsh) available where pressing ESC ESC is enough to rerun a command using `sudo`.

Comment: @EliasProbst, I might look into that ZSH plugin.